# arraylist of arraylist in function calling

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> func(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        ArrayList<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();
        helper(arr,ans,r);
        System.out.println(ans); //print statement 1
        return ans;
    }
    public static void helper(ArrayList<Integer> arr, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans,ArrayList<Integer> r) {
        for(int i =0;i<5;i++){
            r.add(i);
            ans.add(r);
            System.out.println(ans.get(i)); //print statement 2
        }
    }
```

I am trying to print [0],[0, 1],[0, 1, 2],[0, 1, 2, 3],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. 
If I use print statement 1 then I get the output [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]. That is the ans arraylist is automatically updated to the final value of arraylist. I don't know how?? Please help me out.

Comment: Why so complicated? Why do you even need arrays to store the values if you only want to print those numbers (and brackets)?

Comment: You need to add new array list to store new values. Since you are adding r to ans, ans is storing references to r.

Comment: @Drux i am using this code segment in some other Q..where I have to make an arraylist of arraylist

Comment: I see. Well, in `helper` you are always adding to the same array instance `r`, so by the time your reach print statement 1, it it contained 5 times in `ans`. Perhaps you want create `r` only inside the loop in `helper`, that would give you 5 different copies.

Comment: You could do like ans.add(new Arraylist<Integer>(r)); to add new arraylist to ans to store values.

Comment: @pradipforever I understand what you are saying. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ans.add(r)` mean you add `reference of r` in `ans`.

And every changes in `r` after this `add` will also be in `ans.get(indexOfR)`.

So you need to create a new `r` after you add it in `ans`.

Here is a simple way to solve your problem:

```
ArrayList<Integer> r;
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    r = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int ir = 0; ir <= i; ir++) {

        r.add(ir);

    }

    ans.add(r);

}

System.out.println(ans.toString());
//OUTPUT : [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Or you can make a new `r` when add it in `ans`. Like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    r.add(i);

    ans.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(r));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your helper method needs to add separate array list for each iteration of `i`

```
public static void helper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ans) {
    int limit = 1;  
    for(int i =0;i<5;i++){ 
        List<Integer> r = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int j = 0; j < limit) {
           r.add(j);
        }
        ans.add(r);
        limit++;
    }        
}
```